# .class file run using Command Prompt

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to run a .class file i downloaded from the internet, and I'm trying to run it with Command Prompt, when I type:
`java CLASSNAME` it tells me: `Could not find or load main class CLASSNAME` and when I try:
`java -cp CLASSNAME` it gives me:

`Usage: java [options] class [arg...]
    (to execute a class)`

and it does nothing.

Comment: are you running the java command from the location where your class resides ?

Comment: well it should work ..try java -cp . <CLASSNAME>

Answer (score 0):

Some points should be considerd to run java program via CMD:

1. The class that you run, should have a main method.
2. You should type the fully-qualified name of the class that has the main method. For example:

```
java com.example.Main
```

3. You should include the main class, and the required classes/JARs into the classpath.

---

For more details, see the `java` tool reference:

- For Windows: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html
- For Unix: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

Comment: I didn't write it, I got it from the Internet, and it run fine on the web page

Comment: @LOLerKing OK, try `javap className.class`, and see if it has a main method.

Comment: it have: `public class FOO extends BAR { BAZ }`

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake is to include the extension in the class name. You should use `java Foo` and NOT `java Foo.class`.